# Getting JSON from Jersey with circular dependencies

Tags: json, jersey, circular-dependency

I am writing a service that uses Jersey and JAXB. My classes are annotated with @XMLRootElement, @XMLElement, etc. I have a circular dependency between two classes, so I have annotated the circular dependent property with @XMLTransient. So when I call my service I get xml as the default, which works perfectly. However, when I try using JSON, I get repeated lines like:

{"name":"dere","entries":[{"points":0,"wins":0,"losses":0,"ties":0,"leaderboard":{"name":"dere","entries":[{"points":0,"wins":0,"losses":0,"ties":0,"leaderboard":{"name":"dere","entries":[{"points":0,"wins":0,"losses":0,"ties":0,"leaderboard":{"name":"dere","entries":[{"points":0,"wins":0,"losses":0,"ties":0,"leaderboard":{"name":"dere"," ... etc.

So it seems there is a problem with circular dependencies when I am using JSON. I would like to avoid the circular dependent item from showing up in the JSON output, like it is done in XML (because of the @XMLTransient annotation).

Can anyone provide any insight on how I would be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) instead of @XmlTransient to break the circular dependency.

I had a similar problem as you and this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth checking out [Kris Zyp's JSON Referencing proposal](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/). It was invented specifically to handle multiple references and circular references in JSON data.

(Note: Despite the article title, Dojo isn't required. The original proposal was on [json.com](http://json.com), but that site is inaccessible to me at the moment.)

How you would implement this technique in Jersey is, unfortunately, an exercise left to the reader.