# Java object graph to JSON conversion, with cycles

Tags: java, json

How to convert a Java object graph to JSON, where the graph has circular dependencies / cycles?

Comment: I think you'll need to determine what you want from the JSON.  I know in struts2 I can configure includeProperties and exclude properties either by xml or by annotation, this should be able to break the circular dependencies allowing the data to be serialized.

Comment: i convert xml to corresponding java class structure that contain circular dependencies .now i want convert java to json .

Answer (score 7):

There are many open source libraries that can generate JSON. Jersey can break the circular dependencies. For others you might want to google.

- [Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434931/getting-json-from-jersey-with-circular-dependencies) (Use **@JsonIgnore** instead of **@XmlTransient** to break the circular dependency)
- [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (doesn't support circular references. there is a [open defect](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=137) created for this)
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) ([Handle bi-directional references using declarative methods](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences))
- [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) (claims it supports circular references)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** this answer was written a long time ago. Use Gson, Jersey or Jackson.

I went with [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) on my last project. It doesn't bring in any unneeded project dependencies (such as apache-commons jars) and was enough to parse/generate JSON correctly.

You'll still have to manage circular references yourself. I really doubt there is such a library that is built to handle this. You can do this easily by added to a Set any objects that you convert, and then just checking to see if the object you're about to convert is in the set.

Also, I don't think json-simple automatically serializes an object; that is, you have to feed it the data you want added to the JSON. It just handles all of the messy formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you mean by circular dependencies, JSON has no possibility to express references. There are a lot of opensource JSON lib's do check out the link http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html for converting java object to JSON

Answer (score 0):

if you using fasterxml . there is new and call option
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")

. checkout [this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409473/1211174)

just make sure your fasterxml in at the right version for that