# Hibernate Relation cycle via Restful

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, one-to-many, cycle

the code is this:

DB:

Persons(id, name)

Phonenumbers(number, id_persons) FK id_person references Persons(id)

Java code:

```
package com.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.JAXBConfig;

@Entity
@Table(name = "phonenumbers", catalog = "test")
public class Phonenumbers implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8122359598003938895L;
    private String number;
    private Persons persons;

    public Phonenumbers() {
    }

    public Phonenumbers(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Phonenumbers(String number, Persons persons) {
        this.number = number;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "number", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person")
    public Persons getPersons() {
        return this.persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Persons persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

}

 

 

 


package com.app.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "persons", catalog = "test")
public class Persons implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3247756369663156186L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Phonenumbers> phonenumberses = new HashSet<Phonenumbers>(0);

    public Persons() {
    }

    public Persons(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Persons(String name, Set<Phonenumbers> phonenumberses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phonenumberses = phonenumberses;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "persons")
    public Set<Phonenumbers> getPhonenumberses() {
        return this.phonenumberses;
    }

    public void setPhonenumberses(Set<Phonenumbers> phonenumberses) {
        this.phonenumberses = phonenumberses;
    }

}

 

 


package com.app.dao;


import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.app.model.Phonenumbers;

@Stateless
public class PhonenumbersHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PhonenumbersHome.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PhoneBook", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(Phonenumbers transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Phonenumbers instance");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void remove(Phonenumbers persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("removing Phonenumbers instance");
        try {
            entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("remove successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("remove failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Phonenumbers merge(Phonenumbers detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging Phonenumbers instance");
        try {
            Phonenumbers result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Phonenumbers findById(String id) {
        log.debug("getting Phonenumbers instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Phonenumbers instance = entityManager.find(Phonenumbers.class, id);
            log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}






package com.app.dao;


import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.app.model.Persons;

@Stateless
public class PersonsHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PersonsHome.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PhoneBook", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(Persons transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Persons instance");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void remove(Persons persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("removing Persons instance");
        try {
            entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("remove successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("remove failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Persons merge(Persons detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging Persons instance");
        try {
            Persons result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public Persons findById(Integer id) {
        log.debug("getting Persons instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Persons instance = entityManager.find(Persons.class, id);
            log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}

 

 


package com.app.ws;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.app.dao.PersonsHome;
import com.app.model.Persons;

@Path("/persons")
public class PersonsResources {

    @EJB
    private PersonsHome ph;

    @GET()
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Persons getPerson(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        try{
            Context cx = new InitialContext();
            ph = (PersonsHome)cx.lookup("java:module/PersonsHome");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ph.findById(id);
    }
}
```

and this is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="PhoneBook" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>java:/test</jta-data-source>  

     <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
     </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

on link:

```
http://localhost:8080/PhoneBook/persons/1
```

I aspect ad output like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"+01932932"......
```

but I've a cycle like this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":{"id":1,"name":"Roberto","phonenumberses":[{"number":"01932932","persons":
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id"`

check out [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409473/1211174)