# Using Jackson for (De)serialization of Directed Graphs

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, finite-automata

I have these three classes to represent a directed Graph (for Finite State Machines):

```
public class Graph {
    public Set<Node> nodes;

    public Graph(@JsonProperty("nodes") Set<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
                  property = "name")
public class Node {
    public String name;
    public Set<Edge> edges;

    public Node(final String name, final Set<Edge> edges) {
        this.edges = edges;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Node(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this(name, new HashSet<Edge>());
    }
}

public class Edge {
    public String name;
    public Node successor;

    public Edge(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                @JsonProperty("successor") Node successor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.successor = successor;
    }
```

I want to map them to a JSON Object with help of Jackson 2.3.3
The serialization of a simple Graph works flawlessly without infinite backwards references:

```
{
  "nodes" : [ {
    "name" : "Z1",
    "edges" : [ {
      "name" : "0",
      "successor" : {
        "name" : "Z0",
        "edges" : [ {
          "name" : "0",
          "successor" : "Z0"
        }, {
          "name" : "1",
          "successor" : "Z1"
        } ]
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "1",
      "successor" : "Z1"
    } ]
  }, "Z0" ]
}
```

But when I want to deserialize this exact JSON, Jackson is giving me an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve Object Id
    [Z0] (for [simple type, class graph.Node]) -- 
    unresolved forward-reference? (through reference chain: 
    graph.Node["edges"]->graph.Node["edges"])
```

I can see from that, that node Z0 can't be referenced because it is still "under construction", so how do I tell Jackson that it has to construct the nodes first and then add the references in the edges?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779056/java-object-graph-to-json-conversion-with-cycles ?

Comment: I have found that thread too, but it doesn't answer my question :/